# Asking help in a question in elementary number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying exercises of assignment in number theory and I am unable to think about this question.

> Question: Let $f(x)  \equiv  0 (\text{mod p})$ be a congruence of degree $n$ with leading coefficient of $f(x) =1 (\text{mod p})$. Then prove that $f(x) \equiv 0 (\text{mod p}) $has $n$ solutions if and only if $f(x)$ is a factor of $x^p -x  (\text{mod p}) $.

I am unable to think how to relate mod p solution to degree n and n solutions. I tried it but I am unable to get through.

Comment: Ok, now you must be more careful when you write a mathematical question: I suppose $\;p\;$ is a prime number, right? Then write that in the question! Is there given any more information about $\;n\;$ ? Now, are you sure of the last part $\;x^p-x\pmod p\;$ , or perhaps it should be $\;x^{p^n}-x\pmod p\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio rest of the question is fine. p is prime

Comment: Then the question seems to be lacking some sense as if $\;n>p\;$ then $\;f\;$  (which I assume is some polynomial of degree $\;n\;$ cannot be a factor of $\;x^p-x\;$ ...

Comment: The polynomial $(x^3-x)^2$ has degree $6$ and it has $6$ roots $\pmod 3$ (each of $0, \pm 1$ with multiplicity $2$ each).

Comment: If $f(x)$ has no constant term, then $f(x)\equiv0\bmod p$ always has infinitely many solutions, namely the multiples of $p$. Perhaps you intended this to be treated over the finite field $\mathbb F_p$?